# Sentry grant select on only one table in database

Tags: apache-sentry

I am using Cloudera 5.4.2 with Sentry and am successfully granting access to roles on databases.  My challenge now is to have a group that can read only one table from a database that has many other tables.  I have not been able to grant select on a specific table where the role does not have any permissions for the database.  When looking at the Cloudera documentation I do not see an example of this and the wording around granting table access makes is sound straight forward.

Here is an example of what I would like to run to get role `test` access to the table `private_table` without having access to any other tables in the database `testdb`.

```
CREATE ROLE test;
GRANT ROLE test to group `test-group`;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE testdb.private_table TO ROLE test;
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue as in it granted the privileges for that table in default schema instead of "testdb" schema, every time I ran the following command:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE testdb.test_table TO ROLE test;
```

I found a way to workaround this by doing this:

```
USE testdb;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE test_table TO ROLE test;
```

However, since all Hive/Impala queries take `DB.TBL` schema, `GRANT` should also accept it.